# Why does redirect not work? (react-router-dom)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Why does redirect not work?
After executing the function - **onHandleSignInMember ()**, I stay on the same page and do not get to **"/profile"**

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const onHandleSignInMember = () => {
   userSignInFunc(inputsSigninForm);
   return <Redirect to="/profile" />
};
```

Comment: What do you mean *executing the function* ? `Redirect` is a component and needs to be rendered somewhere.

Comment: With the limited code provided, my assumption is that you should actually be using something like [`useHistory`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) and then calling `history.push('/profile')` instead of returning JSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `<Redirect>` is not intended to be used in callbacks but generally wrapped inside a `<Route>` for a render. 
Example usage: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect.

If you need something to immediately "redirect" from a click, consider using the history API `replace`: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history